# Must I have Exchange to use Blackberry Enterprise Server Express?

Tags: active-directory, exchange, blackberry, bes

In the past I've setup BES (not express) for a company that just wanted their users on the corporate network, they didn't care for email or any other enterprise feature, they just wanted to push a policy that the phones internet should be routed through the corporate network.

I want to setup BES Express now for a customer that also just wants the phones on his network but wherever I look, it says that BES Express requires Exchange. Is there a way to install BES Express without Exchange and without a AD Domain?

Basically what the customer wants to accomplish is to be able to filter and log the internet access on the phones.

Comment: I guess if all else fails, I can setup a Domain with Exchange just to install BES without connecting any phones to mailboxes. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Can I ask what the point of buying Blackberries is then?  They're painful at best for Web surfing...

Answer (score 1):

You can run BESX for Exchange or IBM Lotus Domino, but both require a Windows AD domain.

http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/business/server/express/

Answer (score 1):

BES requires Exchange, Domino, or GroupWise (!).  RIM has a separate product called "[BES for MDS Applications](http://us.blackberry.com/apps-software/server/mobile/)" that looks like it might do what you want *if* you're developing your own apps. It doesn't appear that the MDS product has all the management functionality of BES.

Answer (score 1):

BES (and BES Express) is fully supported with the [Zimbra Collaboration Suite](http://www.zimbra.com/) and Zimbra Exchange connector.

We use this setup in production at my work as well as a number of our customers. Works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Lotus Domino does not require Active Directory.  You can set up a standalone Domino server and then use a Blackberry Enterprise server along side.  As long as there is TCP connectivity, the servers can be wherever you like.

So much easier than being tied into everything. (Damn you MS!! )